# Is it good inheritance and interface throught classes?

Tags: php

Hello everyone I would like to know if the following inheritance situation respects the rules of good programming or not.
The situation is:

```
<?php
interface Ainterface {}
interface Binterface {}
class A implements Ainterface{}
class B extends A implements Binterface{}
?>
```

Are there any other possible solutions but especially is this good programming?

Comment: Fundamentally there's no problem here.

Comment: Are there any logical problems?

Comment: No. *this comment needs more characters*